# Determining Swift Types That Can Be Stored in UserDefaults

Tags: ios, swift, macos, plist, userdefaults

I am in the beginning stages of developing [an open-source utility for storing state in the Bundle `UserDefaults`](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs).

I'm encountering an issue when I add non-[`Codable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/codable) data types to my `Dictionary` of `[String: Any]`.

I need to be able to vet the data before trying to submit it, because the [`UserDefaults.set(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set) method won't throw any errors. It just crashes.

So I want to make sure that the `Dictionary` that I'm submitting is kosher.

I can't just check if it's `Codable`, because it can sometimes say that it isn't, when the struct is actually good. (It's a `Dictionary<String, Any>`, and I can cram all kinds of things in there).

I need to validate that the `Dictionary` can produce a plist. If this were ObjC, I might use one of the [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nspropertylistserialization) methods to test the `Dictionary`, but it appears as if this set of methods is not available to Swift.

According to [the `UserDefaults` docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), there are a specific set of types and classes that are "plist-studly."

I think testing each type in the list is unacceptable. I need to see if I can find a way to test that won't be screwed the first time Apple updates an OS.

Is there a good way to test a `Dictionary<String, Any>` to see if it will make [`UserDefaults.set(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults/1414067-set) puke?

Comment: `[String: Any]` never conforms to `Codable` since `Any` doesn't so you don't need to test anything. Maybe you should store your data in struct's or classes instead of a dictionary

Comment: The problem is that it doesn't need to be Codable. [String: Any] can easily be an NSDictionary, which is fine. There's a reason for me using such a general type. I'm making a fairly general base class that allows subclasses to store anything they want in the values Dictionary.

Comment: So what I want to be able to do, is vet the Dictionary before it's sent in, so I can find and report issues without crashing the program.

Comment: I can just let it crash, as this is not likely to be a runtime issue, but the more help I can be to users of my tool, the better.

Comment: "If this were ObjC, I might use one of the NSPropertyListSerialization methods to test the Dictionary, but it appears as if this set of methods is not available to Swift." Can you explain further? It doesn't appear to _me_ as those methods are not available.

Comment: @matt: You are probably correct. Looks like [they stripped off "NS" for Swift](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization).

Comment: Thanks @Josh-Casewell. Good point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Property List type set of `UserDefaults` is very limited. The supported types are

- `NSString` → Swift `String`
- `NSNumber` → Swift `Int`, `Double` or `Bool`
- `NSDate` → Swift `Date`
- `NSData` → Swift `Data`
- Arrays and dictionaries containing the 4 value types.

`Any` is not supported unless it represents one of the 4 value or 2 collection types.

Property List compliant collection types can be written to `UserDefaults` with `PropertyListSerialization` (even in Swift).

---

There are two protocols to serialize custom types to `Data`

- `Codable` can serialize structs and classes.
- `NSCoding` can serialize subclasses of `NSObject`.

All types in the structs/classes must be encodable and decodable (means conform to the protocol themselves).

---

The APIs of `PropertyListSerialization` / `PropertyListEncoder/-Decoder` and `NSKeyed(Un)Archiver` provide robust error handling to avoid crashes.

Comment: I'll greencheck that. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE[1]:** And, just because I like to share, [here's the actual completed project (MIT License, as is most of my stuff)](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs/tree/master)

**UPDATE:** [This is the solution I came up with](https://github.com/RiftValleySoftware/RVS_PersistentPrefs/blob/509f6c112203c13f8fbe35dbb9500101b89bd00b/RVS_Persistent_Prefs/RVS_Base_PersistentPrefs.swift#L48). Even though I greenchecked vadian's excellent answer, I decided to get a bit more picky.

Thanks to matt pointing out that I was looking under the wrong sofa cushions for the keys, I found the Swift variant of [`NSPropertyListSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/propertylistserialization), and I use that to vet the top level of the tree. I suspect that I'll need to refactor it into a recursive crawler before I'm done, but this works for now.

Here's the code for the `_save()` method at the time of this writing. It works:

```
/* ################################################################## */
/**
 This is a private method that saves the current contents of the _values Dictionary to persistent storage, keyed by the value of the "key" property.

 - throws: An error, if the values are not all codable.
 */
private func _save() throws {
    #if DEBUG
        print("Saving Prefs: \(String(describing: _values))")
    #endif

    // What we do here, is "scrub" the values of anything that was added against what is expected.
    var temporaryDict: [String: Any] = [:]
    keys.forEach {
        temporaryDict[$0] = _values[$0]
    }
    _values = temporaryDict

    if PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(_values, isValidFor: .xml) {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(_values, forKey: key)
    } else {
        #if DEBUG
            print("Attempt to set non-codable values!")
        #endif

        // What we do here, is look through our values list, and record the keys of the elements that are not considered Codable. We return those in the error that we throw.
        var valueElementList: [String] = []
        _values.forEach {
            if PropertyListSerialization.propertyList($0.value, isValidFor: .xml) {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("\($0.key) is OK")
                #endif
            } else {
                #if DEBUG
                    print("\($0.key) is not Codable")
                #endif
                valueElementList.append($0.key)
            }
        }
        throw PrefsError.valuesNotCodable(invalidElements: valueElementList)
    }
}
```

Comment: I won't be doing the recursive rabbithole thing. I'll just let the top-level key tell the implementor where to look for the problem. This seems to work perfectly.